# htaccess rewrite for query string

Tags: .htaccess

Ok, im pretty new at this and I would really appreciate some help, thanks!

How can i rewrite this in .htaccess correctly?

So I have a query string in my url:

```
 /?url=contact
```

All i want to do is remove the query string

```
 /contact
```

Help? I scoured google and I'm learning the syntax right now,  but the fact remains..I dont know how to do it just yet. Thanks to all

Comment: Also see this (`Htaccess Redirect URL with Query strings`)https://helponnet.com/2019/06/21/how-to-redirect-a-url-with-query-string-apache-htaccess/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This was my solution:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: This rule is not working for me. While I added your rule, The page will redirect to the welcome page of `xampp`.

Answer (score 30):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

To a user on your site, they will see and navigate to this:

```
http://example.com/contact
```

But the real page would be something like this:

```
http://example.com/index.php?url=contact
```

This bit, `[L]`, tells the server that this is the last line of the rewrite rule and to stop.

Comment: I added the rule as you suggested in my xampp .htaccess file. When I tried to reload my page, it will redirect to localhost/dashboard page. Is there anything missing?

Comment: @Tekson, it's happening to me too and it is due to the /index.php bit. Change it to index.php without the slash.

Answer (score 21):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url=(.*)
RewriteRule index.html  %1
```

(or whatever if it's not index.html, index.php, whatever)

You need to capture the query string, which is not looked at by RewriteRule normally, and use the %1 back reference, not $1 as you would in a capture in a RewriteRule

Answer (score 2):

> Before: *https://example.com/index.php?user=robert*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)?$ index.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

> After: *https://example.com/user/robert*