# .htaccess and PHP profile system

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, profile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [htaccess rewrite for query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231067/htaccess-rewrite-for-query-string)

In the url, to view someone's profile, right now, you go to:

```
http://{url here}/profile/?url={profile url}
```

My question is, how can I make that:

```
http://{url here}/profile/{profile url}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using .htaccess, here is a tutorial to get you started (check 4th example):

http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html

Comment: I have seen this tutorial, but am quite a noob when it comes to htaccess. THANK YOU. Very much, that was exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/profile/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^/profile/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ user.php?url=$1`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have mod_rewrite installed, it's a simple rule in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule /profile/([A-Za-z]+)$    /profile?url=$1
```

The rule assumes your {profile url} variable will always be composed of just characters.

Here's a good [article](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite) on setting up this functionality if you don't already have it (mod_rewrite, that is).

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a rewrite engine.  Assuming you're most likely using Apache since you mentioned .htaccess files, you're in luck, as Apache can do the job for you.  You'll use Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) or [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) extensions to get the job done.

http://www.doriat.com/mod_rewrite6.html has a tutorial dedicated to using mod_rewrite specifically with PHP, but you might find the examples on Apache's own site more helpful.  http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ will let you test your rewrite rules as you write them to take a little frustration out of the equation.