# .htaccess query string to folder format

Tags: .htaccess, query-string, directory-structure

I have a query URL with query string and I want to convert it to folder structured URL.

For example:

```
http://localhost/index.php?page=about-us
http://localhost/index.php?page=contact-us
```

how would I covert it to

```
http://localhost/index/page/about-us
http://localhost/page/about-us
```

I know this can be done with .htaccess. I just don't know where to start

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231067/htaccess-rewrite-for-query-string

Answer (score 1):

You would need something along the lines of...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks   
RewriteEngine On   

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d   
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f   

RewriteRule ^page/([-a-z-0-9]+)*/$ ./index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^index/page/([-a-z-0-9]+)*/$ ./index.php?page=$1
```