# Rewrite url behind url?

Tags: .htaccess

Ok, the title may sound a little weird, but I think that kinda describe it.

So basically I want make this:

`/?url=http://someUrl.com/`

Into this:

`/http://someUrl.com/`

I know how I can do it, if there was no "http://", "https://" or extension... So that's what I ask you guys about :D

I've tried to do `RewriteRule ^([^./]*)$ index.php?url=$1`, but doesn't work with http or extension

http(s), is not a requirement, but it should be able to be there.

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231067/htaccess-rewrite-for-query-string

Comment: @resmon6 If i use one of the answers from that question, I just get a empty page D:

Comment: Are you looking for redirect or rewrite functionality?

Comment: At least show use what your tried, or what worked for you for just-text urls like you described.

Comment: @Gerben try read it again, wrote some new stuff, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using:

```
RewriteRule ^(http.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Comment: Thanks, kind a what I needed.. Played around with yours a little, and came up with this http://regexr.com?3053d I don't know how I got from yours to mine, but i did, so thanks again :D

Comment: Seems like a bit of overkill to detect urls in the path. But if it works, it works.