# How do you rewrite a URL using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm attempting to use htaccess to write my urls as localhost/username instead of localhost/profile.php?id=username

I looked it up and this is what I found to be the solution

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

That's an exact copy from this stackoverflow question [htaccess rewrite for query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231067/htaccess-rewrite-for-query-string) however, for some reason it always returns a 500 error. I'm not sure why it's giving me this since I'm no expert with htaccess. I pretty much just find code modify it to fit my use.

Mod_rewrite is definitely turned on. So I know that can't be the issue. Any idea what is wrong with the code I have?

**Edit:**

This is what the apache error log returned.

[Sat Apr 27 14:20:10.558122 2013] [core:error] [pid 3244:tid 1688] [client 127.0.0.1:58653] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: look at the apache logs

Comment: What does the apache logs say? Are you sure you're allowed to override DirectoryIndex or to issue Rewrite directives?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not great as a web admin. How do I access the apache logs on xampp?

Comment: Nevermind I found it.

Comment: @Denis I edited the post to include the error. It seems as if there's a redirect loop. Any idea why that would be happening?

Comment: Yeah, it's redirecting profile.php to profile.php. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's really a redirect loop per your comment, try adding this line immediately before your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
```

Comment: Thanks, I think we're close. Unfortunately it still threw an error. But I changed the rule to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]` taking away the front slash before profile.php and now if I type in localhost/username it shows the profile.php template but doesn't query the database. Do I have to use $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] in my php code?

Comment: Add a `var_dump($_GET)` in your code somewhere to see what's wrong, and double check your php and mysql details. (Methinks this ought to be a new SO question, too)

Comment: If I can't get it to work after some of my own work I'll make a new question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The part where it says `/profile.php?id=$1` is where it will rewrite you to. If that;s not a file then it would show up with an error so change that to whatever file you want it to rewrite you to.

Hope this helped

- Kevin