# Apache mod rewrite for search in basepath

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i've a little problem with `Apache mod rewrite` configuration.

I need to have an url like this:

http://mysite.com/search+terms

I've tried this config in `htaccess` but it does not work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /search.php?s=$1
```

It return to me an `500 Internal Server Error`.

How I can fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting 500 internal error because of infinite looping since your regex `.*` is always matching even after rewrite. You need to stop this using a RewriteCond. Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ search.php?s=$1 [L,QSA,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this lines,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

and also set the RewriteBase to correct location of **search.php**

**Edit**

I can categorize it as duplicate to [htaccess rewrite for query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231067/htaccess-rewrite-for-query-string)

**Edit 2**

Remove the prefix slash on

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /search.php?s=$1
```

to become

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ search.php?s=$1
```

Comment: Ok, the search.php is in the root directory and the error 500 is shown for all pages of the site (not just when I try to make a search through the new url). Thank you

Comment: could you post the full .htaccess?

Comment: Sure
`RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /search.php?s=$1 [L]`

Comment: well, the problem is this condition ^(.*)$ make all your request to search.php, including index.php request. I suggest make the rule like this
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?s=$1`

but i dont know how your structure are, so I'm just guessing here

Comment: also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231067/htaccess-rewrite-for-query-string

Comment: Ok, i've integrated search.php in index.php and if I go in http://example.com/index.php?s=search+terms it works fine, but if I use a rewrite rule like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?s=$1` it still return me back to `error 500`. I've followed your link but it contain the same rules that i've insert in my htaccess file

Comment: this is silly, but try this:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?s=$1`

notice that i've removed the slash

Comment: Uhm but now all the other pages not work (like css etc) and the homepage go on the search results

Comment: add this

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

check @anubhava answer, he gives you the complete rule

Answer (score 0):

Try this .htaccess code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^search+(.*)$ /search.php?s=$1
```