# Deleting all php extension and get rid of variables in the url

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, get

I got this url

```
/localhost/andalucia/productdetails.php?value=20
```

I want to change it to

```
/localhost/andalucia/productdetails/20
```

how do you do this and how will you get the value 20 in the handler page?

should I change the coding or I just add an ht access file?

If it is adding a ht access file what code should be in it?

How if I have more pages like:

```
/localhost/andalucia/product
/localhost/andalucia/home
/localhost/andalucia/contactus
```

Will they be affected automatically too?
ok i tried to use

```
RewriteRule ^productdetails/([0-9]+)$ productdetails.php?value=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but now the problem is all my **pictures** is gone in the html and i cant open the other **page** like

```
/localhost/andalucia/product
/localhost/andalucia/home
/localhost/andalucia/contactus
```

i need a htaccess code that can open all of these

```
/localhost/andalucia/product
/localhost/andalucia/home
/localhost/andalucia/contactus
/localhost/andalucia/productdetails/20
```

pls helpp someone

Comment: You can do this using htaccess. Google for rewrite rules

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: Check this duplicate for your question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231067/htaccess-rewrite-for-query-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the apache extension `mod_rewrite` it is really easy to transform your pretty URLs into the URLs needed by your script. This `.htaccess` example which you place in your web root should get you going:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^andalucia/productdetails/([0-9]+)$ /andalucia/productdetails.php?value=$1 [L]
```

This example will only rewrite `andalucia/productdetails/NNNN...` format URLs, all other URLs won't be affected. If you need to pass other query parameters, like `/andalucia/productdetails/20?sort=asc` you need to pass the `QSA` flag (query string append) to the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^andalucia/productdetails/([0-9]+)$ /andalucia/productdetails.php?value=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The `L` flag will prohibit the evaluation of next rules. Just look up the `mod_rewrite` documentation for a in-depth discussion!

Comment: i copy paste it delete andalucia in the rewrite rule still no object found i cant do it help