# Rewrite Rule for htcaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I think this has been discussed over here in past but i don't know exactly what i have to search for so please if you could help just give me a hand.
Well i want to create a url rewrite with multiple options. I cannot explain here with few so i would rather give a simple example.
A url:

```
    example.com/info.php?id=1
    example.com/info.php?id=1&edit
```

I want to rewrite to like this

```
    example.com/info/1
    example.com/info/1/edit
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess rewrite for query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231067/htaccess-rewrite-for-query-string)

Comment: I guess it is not and i already tried creating the rule with existing info or articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the opposite: example.com/info/1 -> example.com/info.php?id=1

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^info/([^/]+)/edit/?$ info.php?id=$1&edit   [L]
RewriteRule ^info/([^/]+)/?$    info.php?id=$1  [L]
```

Comment: No, i want example.com/info/1/edit -> example.com/info.php?id=1&edit
Also id can be numberic and alphabetic.

Comment: Alright that worked but what about if there are 2 id like
id=1&userid=2

Comment: For me, the best solution is to send all the link to the PHP page, and take values after. But you can also add (before) 2 or 3 in the htaccess `RewriteRule ^info/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ info.php?id=$1&other=$2`   [L]