# Submit input value without the name in the URL

Tags: php, jquery, forms, .htaccess

Is there a way to submit an input field value without getting its name in the URL?

I use a form with method GET for search, when I submit the form, I get something like this:

```
/file/?inputname=value
```

I want to get it this way:

```
/file/value
```

Otherwise: if the first solution is not possible, how can I modify the .htaccess to rewrite the URL in the above way(I mean: `/file/?inputname=value`), but please take in mind I use 2 parameters in the URL `dir1/file/?inputname=value .`

Thanks in advance

Comment: why u can't go with `post` ??

Comment: I really think about that, and I will do it if we didn't find a solution.

Comment: What happens if you need a second input value?

Comment: .htaccess RewriteRule is the solution .

Comment: Post your current RewriteRule/.htaccess

Comment: @AmitThakur yes, but I don't know how to do it for 2 parameters, one is fixed (fixed name) and the second is changeable and depends on the search keywords.

Comment: .htaccess can make you url looks good like this `/file/inputname/value` instead of this `/file/?inputname=value` but they cant remove your params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: [**Solution Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231067/htaccess-rewrite-for-query-string)

Use .htaccess like below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

To a user on your site, they will see and navigate to this:

```
http://example.com/value
```

But the real page would be something like this:

```
http://example.com/index.php?inputname=value
```

This bit, [L], tells the server that this is the last line of the rewrite rule and to stop.

Answer (score 0):

set your form method to post

```
<form method="post" ...
```

and in your `PHP` file receive data like this

```
$inputValue = $_POST['inputname'];
```

Answer (score 0):

First is not possible.

.htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

PHP

```
    $url = rtrim($_GET['url'], '/');
    $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    $url = explode('/', $url);

    $part1 = (isset($url[0]) ? $url[0] : null);
    $part2 = (isset($url[1]) ? $url[1] : null);
    $part3 = (isset($url[2]) ? $url[2] : null);
    $part4 = (isset($url[3]) ? $url[3] : null);
    $part5 = (isset($url[4]) ? $url[4] : null);

/*
$partN will contain the input after the URL. 
If URL was http://foo.com/this/is/fun
$part1 = this
$part2 = is
$paer3 = fun
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **post** method.

> NOTE:The data sent by POST method goes through HTTP header so security depends on HTTP protocol. By using Secure HTTP you can make sure that your information is secure.

[REFERENCE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm)

ALSO for rewrite rules,try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^dir1/file/$ http://www.my.domain.com/dir1/file [QSA,L]
```