# How to Remove Query String in Dynamic url in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have dynamic url like

```
http://epathasala.com/schooldetails.php?name=john-paul-higher-secondary-school
http://epathasala.com/universitydetails.php?name=demo-university
http://epathasala.com/schooldetails.php?name=tagore-international-school
```

I need to remove all the query string and change the url like below

```
    http://epathasala.com/collegedetails/gtn-arts-college
    http://epathasala.com/universitydetails/demo-university
    http://epathasala.com/schooldetails/tagore-international-school
```

I have tried [Pretty URL - mod_rewrite question][1]  But not working. Please some one help. Thanks

I have tried this below htaccess code but its not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^epathasala/schooldetails/(.*)$ /epathasala/schooldetails.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

I need to remove this part ".php?name=" from the url.

Comment: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` will do the job. Edit: Or do you need it within the `.htaccess`?

Comment: Thanks. I want to use .htaccess

Comment: You can do it with the [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module (see `RewriteEngine` and  `RewriteCond`/`RewriteRule`).

Comment: Yes I have used that only, Please see the question, I updated

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1231088/1057527) would do it.

Comment: I have tried this using htaccess.madewithlove.be/ but not working

Comment: @machineaddict  tried not working thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/?$ $1.php?name=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Yes But schooldetails in not a contsant it may chnage to collegedetails or events or anything.  I need to remove only .php?name=

Comment: I have tried this, and its not working, the url remaining same

Comment: I changed it to fit your needs. Please have a look.

Comment: @GopiKrishnan I looked over it and changed it, please have another try.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/?$ /epathasala/$1.php?name=$2 [NC,L]                                                                                                          tried this But Not working

Comment: @GopiKrishnan Please try again. Also, if it's still not working, please provide the error.

Comment: @GopiKrishnan Then try to explain the behaviour and **how** the *actual* result **differs** from the *expected* one.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^epathasala/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /epathasala/$1.php?name=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Starkeen, I have tried this using htaccess.madewithlove.be but output url not working

RewriteRule ^epathasala/(.*?)/(.*?)/?$ /epathasala/$1.php?name=$2 [NC,L]

Comment: Gopi, check this on your server not on their site.

Comment: Yes Stark. I have checked in my server. I have tried this but not working