# .htaccess redirect variable to friendly link - many redirects

Tags: .htaccess, variables, redirect, clean-urls

I have a problem with htaccess redirecting a variable to clean url.

the code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=$1 [R]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=about$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.url.com/about? [R=301,L]
```

i just want to redirect this: "?page=about" to this: "/about"

and with the code above give me to many redirects...

Thanks for the time to look at this.

Comment: You must see this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231067/htaccess-rewrite-for-query-string

Comment: That solution does not redirect and i have that solution above but does not work properly...

Comment: the first "RewriteRule" give me the friendly urls. but the second redirects to /about like i want but it give me many redirects and i don't no how to solve this....

Answer (score 0):

So i have tried your code in an empty directory on local server.

This works fine:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=$1 [R]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=about$ 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.url.com/about? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But not when i comment out this line of code `RewriteEngine on`. So try your code with this piece of line and it should work fine.

Comment: Sorry but it sill go to error page "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Comment: could you paste you complete .htaccess code? Also, check for any other redirects that is taking place after the above one.

Answer (score 0):

Thats the complete code.

```
#Rewrite settings
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^url.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.url.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#Remove index.php from url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]

#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=about$ 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.url.com/about? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
```

This piece of code is commented because like this does not work:

```
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=about$ 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.url.com/about? [R=301,L]
```