# htaccess rewrite change folder and pass query string

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am new at this. How can I rewrite this in .htaccess correctly?

My visitor access:
http://www.example.com/old/xxx/?id=1

But actually source is from:
http://www.example.com/new/(same name with xxx)/1.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/old/xxx/?id=%1\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.siteurl.org/new/xxx/?id=%1\.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you so much parrycima. How can I deal with xxx (It should be the same name with old one and changing from time to time)

Comment: check out this one. It's similer to your question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44567637/htaccess-redirect-variable-to-friendly-link-many-redirects